# how to remove entities annotated with many to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I've been at this for over 3 hours and no progress. I have this method:

```
  public String deleteShift(Shifts shifts){

     Shifts shiftToBeDeleted = shiftsRepository.findById(shifts.getId()).orElseThrow(() ->new ShiftNotFoundException("This shift doesn't exist"));
           Set<Staff> staffListForShift = shiftToBeDeleted.getStaff();

  if (shiftToBeDeleted.getStaff().isEmpty()){

         System.out.println("this fucker:" + shiftToBeDeleted.getStaff());
         shiftsRepository.deleteById(shifts.getId());
         return "Shift removed.";
     }else {
         for (Staff staff : shiftToBeDeleted.getStaff()){
             System.out.println("this fucker is second:"+ staff.getUsername());
             staff.getShifts().remove(shiftToBeDeleted);
             staffRepository.save(staff);
         }
         shiftsRepository.deleteById(shiftToBeDeleted.getId());
         return "Shift removed, assign the free staff to a different one.";
     }
}
```

it is supposed to delete a shift but it keeps returnning a violation of a foreign key constraint that i can't for the life of me fix.

this is the shifts class :

```
public class Shifts {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private LocalTime shiftStart;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private LocalTime shiftEnd;
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Staff> staff;}
```

this is the staff class :

```
public class Staff {
@Id
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private StaffStates state;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserTypes type;


@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private User user;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "staff")
private Set<WorkHours> workHoursSet;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(
        name = "StaffShifts",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staffId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "shiftId"))
private Set<Shifts> shifts;


@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(
        name = "StaffPermissions",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staffid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permissionId"))
        private Set<Permissions> permissions;

@OneToMany()
private Set<Transactions> transactionsSet;
```

}

i tried using cascade to solve the problem but cascade removal isn't recommended according to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-remove-entity-many-to-many)

Edit : the error is in getStaff.isEMpty(). somehow the list of staff pops up empty in that check but when i move to delete from it it throws a violated foreign key exception.

Comment: why are you not posting the violent exception?

Comment: @Loading what violent exception?

Comment: typo: the violation of the key constraint. Normally the exception helps pinpointing which table did not get cleaned up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not found a solution to this. I resulted to actually creating the staff_shifts entity and mapping it which worked without problems.

Answer (score 0):

To delete with a many to many relationship in hibernate you need to delete *BOTH* sides/entites from each other.

In this part of the code you take the staff entity and remove the shift. But you also need take the shifts entity and remove the staff out of it:

```
shiftToBeDeleted.getStaff().clear(); //SOMETHING LIKE THAT

for (Staff staff : shiftToBeDeleted.getStaff()){
     System.out.println("this fucker is second:"+ staff.getUsername());
     staff.getShifts().remove(shiftToBeDeleted);
     shiftToBeDeleted.getStaff().remove(staff); //SOMETHING LIKE THAT
     staffRepository.save(staff);
 }
```

I can also imagine that you need to change the cascade to also add DELETE:

```
cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}
```

Comment: cascade.REMOVE isn't recommended for many to many that's why i didn't use it. also the exception is not there. It's in the if check for staff

Comment: can you please add these to the post? Its hard to follow exactly where you get the exception. Also did the getStaff().clear() work?

Comment: i did add that CASCADE.REMOVE isn't recommended as per the article i shared.

Comment: sorry its hard to follow you. On which line do you get the exception exactly? Can you post the exception message? did the clear() work or not?

Comment: I removed the problem entirely by actually declaring the staff_shifts entity. I'll close the question. Thanks for helping!